# Supporting international keyboard layouts with Monogame?

Tags: c#, keyboard, monogame

I have a Dictionary that maps Monogame Keys to characters. For example, hitting Keys.A will return "a" or "A", depending on if shift is held down. The characters are then relayed to input boxes in my UI.

It works fine for people with American keyboard layouts, but the testers in Europe (ex. France and Finland) are reporting that when they try to type special characters/punctuation, the character that is typed is different than the key they press.

How can I add keyboard support for my testers in Europe?

Comment: Can you explain what character was written down instead of what they expect?

Comment: @Steven This is their keyboard format. https://i.stack.imgur.com/leHzl.png


They were having issues with any of the special punctuation characters that differ from my American keyboard layout, which looks like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg/400px-KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg.png

Comment: Odd, I thought I would understand it more as I was from Europe, but appearantly I'm using an US keyboard instead. So it's hard for me to understand what's going on. Sorry.